# RDF + OWL reasoning

Tags: sql, database, rdf, owl, reasoning

Let's suppose I have an RDF data about Socrates. The data is shown below

```
subject, predicate, object
man, being, mortal
Socrates, being, man
```

To check whether Socrates is mortal I have a request

```
SELECT *
FROM RDFData t1
JOIN RDFData t2
ON t1.subject = t2.object
```

Then I have a filter on "Socrates" and "mortal" and if result is not empty, then Socrates is mortal.

It works fine, but my teacher asks to add OWL information.

For example, if we have the next data

```
subject, predicate, object
man, being, mortal
Socrates, being, Greek
Greek, being, man
```

My approach does not work, because we have additional step in the chain.

I need to add an OWL static data here and implement a request for arbitrary number of steps in the chain.

What are my next steps?

Comment: I'd say your next step is to give up trying to do this stuff in SQL and instead use an actual RDF database, possibly with an OWL reasoner on top... Not trying to be flippant, I genuinely think you are taking a dead-end approach.

Comment: why did you open a second question with exactly the same problem?!

Comment: and to keep it short, you have to apply the SQL query in a fixpoint-iteration...that's exactly the same procedure that any OWL/RDFS rule-based reasoning engine is also doing. taht has to be done on application side. or write a stored procedure. are look for a SQL database that supports recursive queries.

Answer (score 3):

If we turn your example data into actual RDF (using [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) syntax), you'd get something like this:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:socrates rdf:type :Greek .
:Man rdfs:subClassOf :Mortal .
:Greek rdfs:subClassOf :Man .
```

If you upload this data into an RDF database (such as RDF4J, Jena, GraphDB, Stardog, Blazegraph, or a host of other options), you can use the following SPARQL query:

```
ASK WHERE { :socrates rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* :Mortal }
```

This checks if `:socrates` is of a type that is either `:Mortal`, or a (direct or indirect) subclass of `:Mortal`. It returns `true` if Socrates is a mortal, `false` otherwise. You don't even need a reasoner for this, you can just use the expressivity of the query language.

If your RDF database supports basic RDFS reasoning, you can simplify your query even further:

```
ASK WHERE { :socrates rdf:type :Mortal }
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! But I cannot use existing RDF database. I should have 2 CSV files. The first is dynamic data. And the second is for OWL data. I cannot catch what should be in these files and how can I do a request?

Comment: @renataleb why did you open a second question with exactly the same problem?!

Comment: @AKSW This is another question. Here I have to use an OWL

Comment: @renataleb what is "an OWL"? and it's exactly the same, OWL axioms have to be encoded as RDF triples as long as you want to use your triples table ... the SQL queries are the same, and as said in my comment, you have to apply fixpoint iteration in your application - sorry to say that, that's the same thing a rule engine has to done.

Comment: @renataleb you should question the requirements your teacher is putting in place. OWL ontologies are not CSV files - the closest representation is N-TRIPLE - but why would you represent them as CSV files? There is nothing to gain and a lot to lose because of those constraints. Also, most of the libraries Jeen mentioned can be used entirely in memory, without any intermediate storage, so "not being able to use a triple store" is not a valid objection. I don't think it's a valid requirement either, but that's another story.